# For loop with in another for loop in aura javascript causes performance issue how to overcome on this issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller, aura-iteration

Here is the code snippet
where my filterList is original list contains 300 records data and newList contains the selected list values which an 165 as example as below for loop causes an performance issue

```
  for(var i=0;i<filterList.length;i++)  
                        {   
                            var count=false;    
                            for(var j=0;j<newList.length;j++)   
                            {   
                                    
                                if(filterList[i].Id==newList[j].Id) 
                                {   
                                    count=true; 
                                    break;  
                                    //filterList.splice(i,1);   
                                }   
                            }   
                            if(count==true) 
                            {   
                                console.log('list displayed');
                                newfilterList.push(filterList[i]);      
                            }   
                                
                        }
                        filterList=newfilterList
                        component.set("v.filterMemberList", filterList);
            var memberList = [];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Set above code can be optimized. Complexity will be reduced from 300*165 to 300+165 lines for checking, if filterdList element id matches with newList element id.

```
var newList = response.getReturnValue();
var newfilterList = [];
let newListIdSet = new Set();
for (var j = 0; j < newList.length; j++) {
    newListIdSet.add(newList[j].Id);
}

for (var i = 0; i < filterList.length; i++) {

    if (newListIdSet.has(filterList[i].Id)) {
        newfilterList.push(filterList[i]);
    }
}

filterList = newfilterList
component.set("v.filterMemberList", filterList);
```

With ecmascript this code can be again reduced.

```
const newList = response.getReturnValue();
let newListIdSet = new Set();

newList.forEach(element=> newListIdSet.add(element.Id));

const newfilterList = filterList.filter(element=> newListIdSet.has(element.Id));

component.set("v.filterMemberList", newfilterList);
```

Comment: Even I have tried this approach before but it takes  more time and not getting the correct result with this approach .

Comment: Can you post your code with this approach, that will be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: Loading time also depends upon DOM as well, please post cmp file as well.

Comment: Hi Amit

I have updated the cmp and js file in the code snippet. I am thinking that even in cmp currentpagerecord for pagination is also cause and issue because of multipel iteration of renders.

Comment: On above approach using set as well its getting the same performance issue

Comment: issue has been resolved with another set of index id in iteration value.